# How to replace missing data with last available value in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

is there anyway in pandas I can do to do imputation from its last available value for each ID?

| ID | Week | Category |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1001 | 1 | A |
| 1001 | 2 | A |
| 1001 | 3 |  |
| 1001 | 4 | B |
| 1002 | 1 | B |
| 1002 | 2 |  |
| 1002 | 3 | C |
| 1002 | 4 |  |

I would like to transform it to below dataframe

| ID | Week | Category |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1001 | 1 | A |
| 1001 | 2 | A |
| 1001 | 3 | A |
| 1001 | 4 | B |
| 1002 | 1 | B |
| 1002 | 2 | B |
| 1002 | 3 | C |
| 1002 | 4 | C |

Thanks in advance for the helps.

Answer (score 3):

You have not really described what you wanted, but it looks like you’re looking for [`ffill()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.2.0/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ffill.html) (or `fillna(method='ffill')`). This replaces missing values (`na`) with previous elements (hence `f`orward `fill`).

```py
>>> df
      Week Category
ID                 
1001     1        A
1001     2        A
1001     3     None
1001     4        B
1002     1        B
1002     2     None
1002     3        C
1002     4     None
>>> df['Category'] = df['Category'].ffill()
>>> df
      Week Category
ID                 
1001     1        A
1001     2        A
1001     3        A
1001     4        B
1002     1        B
1002     2        B
1002     3        C
1002     4        C
```

If your missing values are something else, for example empty strings, you can remove those with [`.mask()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.2.0/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html) and then use the same solution.

```
>>> df['Category'].mask(df['Category'] == '').ffill()
ID
1001    A
1001    A
1001    A
1001    B
1002    B
1002    B
1002    C
1002    C
Name: Category, dtype: object
```

If you want to limit that per ID, you can use [`GroupBy.ffill()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.2.0/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.ffill.html).

This only gives different results from the previous solution if you have an empty value at the beginning of an ID. If you don’t want it to be populated from the previous ID, see below:

```
>>> df
      Week Category
ID                 
1001     1        A
1001     2        A
1001     3     None
1001     4        B
1002     1     None
1002     2     None
1002     3        C
1002     4     None
>>> df.groupby('ID')['Category'].ffill()
ID
1001      A
1001      A
1001      A
1001      B
1002    NaN
1002    NaN
1002      C
1002      C
Name: Category, dtype: object
>>> df['Category'].ffill()
ID
1001    A
1001    A
1001    A
1001    B
1002    B
1002    B
1002    C
1002    C
Name: Category, dtype: object
```

Comment: If the first value of category of specific ID (e.g. 1002) is missing, it will fill it with the last available category of previous ID, I want it to be fill within each unique ID and not taking value from previous ID, how can I do that?

Comment: Thanks, it really helpful